# How do I write the value back into the structure via the asynchronous closure in rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

```
fn execute<F: std::future::Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static>(f: F) {
        // this is stupid... use any executor of your choice instead
        std::thread::spawn(move || pollster::block_on(f));
}

struct Test {
    pub a: String,
}

impl Test {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        if true {
            let task = rfd::AsyncFileDialog::new().pick_file();

            execute(async {
                let file = task.await;
                if let Some(file) = file {
                    println!("{:?}", file.path());
                    self.a = file.file_name();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error message.
borrowed data escapes outside of associated function`self` escapes the associated function body hererustcE0521
mod.rs(138, 15): `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
mod.rs(138, 15): let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`rustcE0521
mod.rs(138, 15): `self` is a reference that is only valid in the associated function body
mod.rs(138, 15): let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Please don't copy errors from your IDE, instead copy the message from `cargo check`.

Comment: Also, if you reference external code (`rfd` and `pollster`) please provide a mock/explanation for how to compile your minimal example (or if it doesn't compile, how to reproduce your error message)

Comment: I apologise for this, my English is not very good and the translation software cannot accurately describe the problem I am experiencing

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll take care of it next time

Comment: You can change your question :) I doubt your will get an answer otherwise

Comment: But to your actual question: Why do you spawn a thread to execute an async function?